# How to create a sizing formula based on logarithmic requirements

Tags: javascript, css, algorithm, math

I am creating a piece of UI that needs to adjust to size of elements the further away they get from the centre.

Specifically, the further elements are from the centre, the smaller they need to be. I am going to do this with CSS `transform: scale(x)`.

The distance units come as such:

```
0 (at the centre, no adjust needed)
1
2
3
4
... and so on
```

Because I am using `scale(x)`, I need to transform `1, 2, 3, 4..` into values like `0.8, 0.65, 0.4, 0.25`, etc, so that:

```
1 = 0.85
2 = 0.65
3 = 0.4
4 = 0.25
```

**This is just an approximation, the output numbers don't need to be exact, just a nice curve.**

How can this be done with JavaScript? I know it is a simple math question but I cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: `1 - index/length` for linear or `1 * 0.5 ** i`

Comment: @Jonasw "just a nice curve" ... not looking for linear

Comment: don't be harsh, linears can be a "nice curve" too.. don't hurt them feelings! By the way what you describe "further elements are from the centre, the smaller.." fits to a linear relation. Maybe it would be easier for us to find a formula if we have more precise rules, like minimum reduction rate for the maximum position from center, etc

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Math.exp(-x)` . It will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can pick any mathematical function and experiment a little bit to get the right boundaries.

For example lets take the cos function 
cos(0) = 1; cos(pi/2) = 0; 
in this case interpolating our length and index to pi/2 will do the trick.

```
var calcScale = (index, length) => {
    let x = ((Math.PI/2) * index)/length;
    return Math.cos(x);
};
```